# Passing mongdb function from python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

This works well to query the Timestamp in Mongodb.
using **mongodb internal function: new Date () - to generate TimeStamp.**

```
 db.mycollection.find({'timeStamp':new Date("2019-11-02T04:00:00.110Z").getTime()}).limit(1)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dd21850d527ae105b37b08b"), "name" : vkg }
```

but the same when trying from pymongo , its giving syntax error. 
Am interested in passing the timeStamp Conversion to Mongodb itself instead of python doing it.

```
db.mycollection.find({'timeStamp':new Date("2019-11-02T04:00:00.110Z").getTime()}).limit(1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    db.mycollection.find({'timeStamp':new Date("2019-11-02T04:00:00.110Z").getTime()}).limit(1)
                                             ^
**SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

I tried quotes / double quotes etc to make it literal , but didn't work.

How to pass the native Mongodb function passed using pymongo?

Answer (score 0):

You should use python datetime's, because Date is javascript object. See my another [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841132/fetch-3-days-data-from-mongodb-using-python/58841550#58841550)